# Adding Items to the Grid View: Index was out of range exception

Tags: c#, exception, gridview

I'm trying to add items in a GridView using the following code but it is throwing the exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in 'mscorlib.dll' but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Here is my code:

```
 protected void GridViewProduct_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
     {
         int RowClicked = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewProduct.DataKeys[RowClicked].Value);
         List<int> ProductsInCart = (List<int>)Session["Cart"];
         if (ProductsInCart == null)
         {
             ProductsInCart = new List<int>();
         }
         ProductsInCart.Add(ProductID);
         Session["Cart"] = ProductsInCart;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Which line throws an exception?

Comment: GridViewProduct.DataKeys[RowClicked] looks suspect in that line. have you checked to see if what is in DataKeys and also what rowclicked has?

Comment: int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewProduct.DataKeys[RowClicked].Value);

Receiving Exception at this line !

Comment: The count of DataKeys is 0

Comment: RowClicked has the value of the row that I click for ex: 2

Answer (score 0):

Which line is throwing this exception?  You should probably check and make sure Session["Cart"] is not null before casting to a List.  There's a plethora of reasons why you may lose that session object.  Also make sure RowClicked isn't null as this can cause the exception as well.
Set a breakpoint in the beginning of this event (if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")), then step through and check each line of code for null references.
As an example:

```
if(Session["Cart"] != null)
  {
     // Then cast to list
  }
```

Comment: It is throwing the exception at 
int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewProduct.DataKeys[RowClicked].Value);

Comment: You mentioned that the count of DataKeys was 0.  If there are no DataKeys, then you can't reference an index of DataKeys.  I'd find out why DataKeys is empty.  Without seeing more of your program or knowing what you're trying to do, I can't be of much more help.